# What is the correct way of creating a document that can be queried by any of its elements?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on a project in which I want all documents in a "pool" to be returned by searching for any element in the pool.

So for instance lets say we have 3 pools, each with varying documents labeled by letter

Pool 1: `A, B, C`

Pool 2: `D`

Pool 3: `E, F, G, H`

When I search for `A`, I want to get `A`, `B`, and `C`. When I search `C`, I also want to get `A`, `B`, and `C`.

If I add a document `I`, and it satisfies criteria for Pool 1 and 2, then Pools 1 and 2 should be merged, and any search for any `A, B, C, D, I` should return all of them.

I know how to do this inefficiently (create a new document with each element as key, then update all documents on each insertion), but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at [indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)?

Comment: Or maybe thought of just rewriting your query to look at the elements in the document, instead of just looking at the key?

Comment: Or modifying the document/collection *design* so that querying it is easy?

Comment: Or a combination of above approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that with something as abstract as data, particularly database documents, a good visualization helps with conceptualizing the problem. Try viewing this problem from the perspective of attempting to maintain a set of trees of depth no more than 1. Specifically, each document is a leaf and the "rules" that determine which ones are part of the "pool" are the root (i.e. the root is the subset of labels that can be a leaf).

Now, what you're saying you want to do is to be able to add a new leaf. If this leaf is able to connect to more than one root, then those roots should be merged, which means updating what the root is and pointing every leaf from the affected trees to this new root.

Otherwise, what you end up with is the need to jump around from the new leaf to each of the roots it connects to and then to every other leaf. But each other leaf could potentially also be connected to other roots, which means you could be jumping around like this an arbitrary number of times. This is a non-ideal situation.

In order for this query to be efficient, you need to decide what these "roots" are going to be and update those accordingly. You may, for instance, decide to keep a "pool" document and merge these "pools" together as needed, e.g. by having a `labels` field that is an array of labels to be included in the pool. Merging is then just a matter of merging the arrays themselves. Alternatively, you could use a common ObjectId (not necessarily attached to any particular document) and use this value as a sort of "pseudo root node" in place of having documents. There are a number of options you could explore. In general, however, you should try to reduce any examining of field values for individual documents down to a single value check (e.g. don't keep arrays of other "related" labels in each document!).

Regardless of your approach, keep these tree structures in mind, consider what it means to traverse the nodes in terms of MongoDB queries, and determine how you want to traverse the nodes in order to 1) ensure that the number of "hops" you need between nodes is a constant-time operation, and 2) ensure that you can efficiently and reliably merge those roots without risk of data loss.

Finally, if you're finding that your update queries are too slow, then you're probably running into indexing problems. With proper indexes, updates on collections with even millions of documents shouldn't take any time at all. Additionally, if you're not doing a `multi` update and are instead running an individual update for each document, then your updates are badly written because you'll be running into `O(n)` search time and network overhead, which will slow your updates down to a crawl.